# recursive proof for a congruence relation lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The result I am trying to prove:

$$n-m \Biggl\lfloor \frac{n}{m} \Biggr\rfloor =1 \Leftarrow\Rightarrow n^k\equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} m)\quad \forall k \in \mathbb N \land n,m \in \mathbb N \,\backslash\, {\{1}\}$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(0.0)$$

My attempt thus far:

$$n-m \Biggl\lfloor \frac{n}{m} \Biggr\rfloor =1 \Leftarrow\Rightarrow n-1-m \Biggl\lfloor \frac{n-1}{m} \Biggr\rfloor =0 $$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1.0)$$

$$n-1-m \Biggl\lfloor \frac{n-1}{m} \Biggr\rfloor =0 \Leftarrow\Rightarrow n\equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} m)$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2.0)$$

Using the compatibility of the congruence relation with multiplication:

$$a_1\equiv a_2 (\operatorname{mod} N) \land b_1\equiv b_2 (\operatorname{mod} N) \Rightarrow a_1b_1\equiv a_2 b_2 (\operatorname{mod} N) $$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(3.0)$$

By simply substituting $a_1=b_1=n$, $a_2=b_2=1$ and $N=m$:

$$n\equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} m)\Rightarrow n^2\equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} m) $$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(4.0)$$

and repeating this substitution a total number of times equal to   $2\Bigl\lfloor\frac{k}{2} \Bigr\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}((-1)^k-1)$ recursively will yield:

$$n^{2\Bigl\lfloor\frac{k}{2} \Bigr\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}((-1)^k-1)}\equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} m) \Rightarrow n^k\equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} m) $$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(5.0)$$

And this inductively proves the result for all naturals $k$.

edit* I think I have missed a lemma of establishing $n$ and $m$ are coprime

Comment: once you get $n\equiv1\mod m$ you have a base case for induction and assuming $n\equiv1 \bmod m$ and $n^k\equiv1\bmod m$ then $n^{k+1}=n^kn\equiv1\times1\equiv1\bmod m$, so $n^k\equiv1\bmod m$ for all naturals $k$

Comment: Ah true that's a lot neater

Comment: The LHS is $\, n\bmod m = 1\,$ and the RHS is equivalent to $\ n\equiv 1\pmod{\!m}\ $ and they are equivalent as is well-known (and proved here in many places).